# Minimum wage data via DoL API

Tags: labor

I am trying to access the following type of info: https://www.dol.gov/whd/minwage/america.htm#Consolidated

through the Dept of Labors API.

Using the method outlined here: [Beginners Guide Method](http://developer.dol.gov/beginners-guide)

I am able to access all other available datasets aside from the one that sounds like it might have this data: [Wage dataset](http://developer.dol.gov/keeping-what-you-earn/wage-and-hour-publications-system)

For instance, when using my generated API Key, this works fine: [Working Query](http://api.dol.gov/V1/Statistics/CPS/LE_AGES/?KEY=xxxx)

but all of the following fail with a 404:

http://api.dol.gov/V1/WHPS/PublicationsView/?KEY=xxxx
http://api.dol.gov/V1/WHPS/Publications/?KEY=xxxx
http://api.dol.gov/V1/WHPS/DocumentsView/?KEY=xxxx
http://api.dol.gov/V1/WHPS/Documents/?KEY=xxxx

According to the [Wage and Hour Publications System (WHPS)](http://developer.dol.gov/keeping-what-you-earn/wage-and-hour-publications-system) it should work, however the [WHPS API URL throws a 404](http://api.dol.gov/V1/WHPS).

Comment: comment your links here and i'll edit it

Comment: Method from the beginners guide: http://developer.dol.gov/beginners-guide    
<br/>
Wage dataset: http://developer.dol.gov/keeping-what-you-earn/wage-and-hour-publications-system    
<br/>
working query: http://api.dol.gov/V1/Statistics/CPS/LE_AGES/?KEY=xxxx    
<br/>
http://api.dol.gov/V1/WHPS/PublicationsView/?KEY=xxxx    
<br/>
http://api.dol.gov/V1/WHPS/Publications/?KEY=xxxx    
<br/>
http://api.dol.gov/V1/WHPS/DocumentsView/?KEY=xxxx    
<br/>
http://api.dol.gov/V1/WHPS/Documents/?KEY=xxxx

Comment: ok, think i got it for you. i agree that its very frustrating and worthless to some extent for new users to have limitations sent...the flip is that without limitations, spam gets out of control and ruins the site for everyone. again, its rough for new users, i wish there were better methods in place. only edited that out bc its not pertinent to your question. feel free to bring it up in meta

Comment: np, lmk if you need more....

Answer (score 1):

There is something broken with our API's access to the Wage and Hour Division's data.  We're working hard to get that restored.

Comment: Is there any ETA?  I looked on github USDepartmentofLabor/Developer but didn't see anything under the issues section.


Thanks!

Comment: andy update, 2.5 yrs later?